# User-Agent question

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, esp8266, networking

I've seen a few different User-Agents used in demo sketches and am curious as to what the various User-Agent options are and how to determine which one to use.

For example...
    `User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0`
    `User-Agent: Arduino/1.0`
    `User-Agent: ESP8266`
    `User-Agent: ArduinoWiFi/1.1`

I've used Arduino/1.0 successfully with an Uno/WiFi101 but want to use an ESP8266 now.  Do I continue using Arduino/1.0 or switch to ESP8266 (Arduino IDE 1.6.5)?

When would someone use Mozilla?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use anything you like. It's used by the remote server to (try and) determine what browser you're using in order to give you the best visual experience. On an Arduino you really don't care about the visual experience. You don't even *need* to provide a `User-Agent` field, but it is courteous to do so.